# Knowing the base of something

Tags: word-choice

I am wondering what you would say when you would like to say that someone should ***know the fudamental or basic of something (know the basis of something)*** or should know the basic elements or parts of something like writing an essay, so that one can write it well.

Take this, for example:

> You should know the basis of research so as to your article to be accepted or published somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just simply say:

> You should know the basics first.

or:

> You should know the fundamentals first.

With your example on research, I would say

> You should know the basics (fundamentals) of doing research first so your article will be published.

Comment: Nina, It would also help to know a but more of the basics of English syntax—or else to have a good editor, such as Jimmy S!

Answer (score -1):

You can use this phrase :

> Your concepts should be clear.

Example :

```
In order to pursue higher studies in computers, ones concepts must be clear or solid.
```

Comment: How do you say the bold part??

Comment: as a native speaker, I would never say this.  You don't talk about "your concepts", you can say "you must understand *the* basic concepts", or similar.